# What is the issue in my array division step?

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am working on a program to run a Monte Carlo simulation in Python.   The program is supposed to approximate the integral of x/((1 + x^2)^2) from x = 0 to infinity.   I believe I have an issue with my array division.   The analytical answer is 1/2, but for some reason the answer I am getting is always negative.   Here is the code I have so far.

```py
# importing module
import numpy as np
import statistics
import math
import random

random.seed(123456)
U = np.random.uniform(0,1,100000)
print(U)

T = np.divide(1/U - 1), 2*U**2 - 2*U + 1)

ans = statistics.mean(T)
print(ans)
```

Any help is much appreciated!   Again, I believe it is on the step that I define T where I have the issue.

Comment: Try testing with a smaller array, 5 or 10 elements, so you can look at `T` to make sure it looks like what you expect.

Comment: `U-1` will be negative, so `1/(U - 1)` will also be negative. If `2*U**2 - 2*U + 1` is positive, the result of the division will be negative.

Comment: `T = np.divide(1/U - 1), 2*U**2 - 2*U + 1)` is IMHO invalid - 1 opening bracket and 2 closing brackets. And its formula is not the same as in the text before _x/((1 + x^2)^2)_ - is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. Rewrite integral as

∫<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup> x/(1+x<sup>2</sup>) 1/(1+x<sup>2</sup>) dx

From w(x) = 1/(1+x<sup>2</sup>) I would sample random numbers and mean of g(x)=x/(1+x<sup>2</sup>) would provide us with the answer

Along the lines (Python 3.9 Win10 x64)

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

N = 100000
U = rng.random(N)

W = np.tan(U*np.pi/2.0)

G = W/(1.0+W*W)

ans = np.mean(G)*np.pi/2.0
print(ans)
```

prints answer

```
0.5000070541974223
```