# Calculate the improper integral Monte Carlo method

Tags: transform, montecarlo

For exaple, I'm trying to transform the integral:

[image: The improper integral]

I need to transform it to an integral that goes from 0 to 1 (or from a to b) in order to apply the algorithm of Monte Carlo I implemented. I already have Monte Carlo function, which calculate definite integrals, but I need to transform this improper integral to definite integral and I really don't know how to do it.

Ideally, I want to transform this integral (from -inf to inf):

[image]

Also I tried to do transformation, which I found on Inthernet (integration by substitution: x=-ln(y), dx=-1/y), but it doesn't work:

[image]

So how can I get transformation of this integral?

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to transform it to an integral that goes from 0 to 1 (or from a to b) in order to apply the algorithm of Monte Carlo I implemented.

No, you don't.

if you have integral

∫<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup> w(x) g(x) dx

you could sample from w(x) and compute mean value of g(x) at sampled points.

You integral

∫<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup> e<sup>-x</sup> cos(x) dx

is pretty perfect for such approach - you sample from e<sup>-x</sup> and compute E[cos(x)]

Along the lines (Python 3.9, Win10 x64)

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

N = 1000000
U = rng.random(N)

W = -np.log(1.0 - U) # sampling exp(-x)

G = np.cos(W)

ans = np.mean(G)
print(ans)
```

will print something like

```
0.5002769491719996
```

And concerning your second integral, see [What is the issue in my array division step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793928/what-is-the-issue-in-my-array-division-step/70794613#70794613)